# Non-parametric test for unimodality of 2-d dataset

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, nonparametric, mode

I'm looking for a method to determine if a 2-d dataset forms a single cluster or is split into two/multiple clusters - and what's the likelihood or p-value for this. Isolated data should not be considered as different cluster. Also, data has a non-parametric distribution.

My approach is to apply an unimodal / bimodal test. However, I didn't find any modality statistical test for 2-d non-parametric data.

An alternative approach is to check the modality of the projections of the data on the two axis (this becomes a 1-d modality test). If the distributions of the projections are unimodal on both axis, then the 2-d dataset has a unimodal distribution.

If this alternative approach is correct, then my question becomes: what unimodality test to use for 1-d non-parametric data? - I already tried the DipTest R implementation, but it doesn't work correctly in the non-parametric case (see the example below).

An example illustrating the alternative approach below: (first two plots - histograms of the projection of the data on the OX and OY axes; the third plot - scatterplot of the 2-d dataset)

- Example for unimodal distribution - unimodal distribution on both axes (inferred from the histograms)

!! inconsistent results from DipTest: pval_x = 0.06 & pval_y = 0.05 (which means significant bimodlity on both axis - which is not true)

[image: unimodal]
<sub>(source: [mdragan at swarm.cs.pub.ro](https://swarm.cs.pub.ro/%7Emdragan/gsoc2013/genevalidator/stat/unimodal.png))</sub>

- Example for multi-modal distribution

[image: bimodal]
<sub>(source: [mdragan at swarm.cs.pub.ro](https://swarm.cs.pub.ro/%7Emdragan/gsoc2013/genevalidator/stat/bimodal.png))</sub>

Comment: There are many [possibly relevant posts here](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=test+of+unimodality++++site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com)